# How to keep Google Identity Toolkit session active after app is terminated?

Tags: ios, sdk, launch, google-signin, google-identity-toolkit

I'm using Google Identity Toolkit and so far it's working great. My question is how to check in `didLaunchWithOptions:` if there's a current session active in this device so I can skip the authentication.

I tried with `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser != nil` but it returns false after the app is forcedly terminated.

If I call `GITAuth.sharedInstance().signInWithSavedAccount()` it will attempt to login with the last used account, however by the time it comes back I would've already presented the login screen, which is not the expected behavior.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you want to achieve is that once a user signs into your app, the app can always keep the user in the login state even if the app is terminated and re-opened, and the user does not the login again. Your app could save the login user state into a safe place on the device, like Keychain, and delete the state info when the user signs out.

Comment: It's not the answer that I was looking for, but might be a workaround to keep the session artificially. The issue in this case is that the user won't be actually authenticated and if you try to access any information with these credentials, it will fail. Thanks for the idea though.